# Why are there fewer objects when I use “dyntopo” to sculpt small objects?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

I don't press CTRL.
The little object gradually disappeared.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution to the problem.Increase the value of resolution...

Comment: Hi, good for you but a little cryptic for others to learn from your experience :) You could add more info about which resolution value worked well for you, and maybe some visual reference to compare with what you asked...